# Custom Validation Attribute - IsValid() parameter is null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, customvalidator, validationattribute

I'm using Simon Ince's RequiredIf custom validation attribute implementation.  For most situations it has been working, however, I have come into a situation that doesn't work and I can't seem to figure out why.

Here is the relevant portion of the model:

```
public class SiteOptionsViewModel
{
    public short? RetrievalVendorID { get; set; }
    public short? CopyServiceID { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Select Retrieval Method For Site")]
    public short? RetrievalMethodID { get; set; }
    //drop down list items
    [DisplayName(@"Retrieval Vendor")]
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> RetrievalVendors { get; set; }
    [RequiredIf("RetrievalMethodID", 10, ErrorMessage = @"Copy Service required if Retrieval Method = OS")]
    [DisplayName(@"Copy Service")]
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CopyServices { get; set; }
    [DisplayName(@"Record Format")]
    public IEnumerable<ExtendedSelectListItem> RetrievalMethods { get; set; }
}
```

In the RequiredIfAttribute class, we have to override the IsValid() method:

```
protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
{
    // check if the current value matches the target value
    if (ShouldRunValidation(value, this.DependentProperty, this.TargetValue, validationContext))
    {
        // match => means we should try validating this field
        if (!_innerAttribute.IsValid(value))
            // validation failed - return an error
            return new ValidationResult(FormatErrorMessage(validationContext.DisplayName), new[] { validationContext.MemberName });
    }
    return ValidationResult.Success;
}
```

You'll notice that the two properties in the model that are relevant are both `IEnumerable<SelectedListItem>` types for use by dropdowns.  The requirement is that when a user selects a particular value from the Retrieval Method dropdown, the form must now require a value to be selected from the Copy Service dropdown.  The problem I'm having is that when `IsValid()` is called on the `RequiredIf` attribute, the value parameter is null, even when a value has been selected in the Copy Service dropdown.  So, the Copy Service gets flagged as being required even though a value has been selected.  Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: You do not apply the attribute to the `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` property (or the `DisplayName` attributes) - that property is just used for providing the values to generate the options). You apply it to the property your binding to (which I assume is `CopyServiceID` but you have not shown your view)

Comment: But using a `[RequiredIf]` in this case makes no sense. You already have a [Required]` attribute on `RetrievalMethodID` so therefore you only need to add a `[Required]` attribute to `CopyServiceID` - there is not conditional evaluation since `RetrievalMethodID` is also required

Comment: @StephenMuecke You are, of course, correct.  I am certainly not at my best on Friday afternoons.  As my mind worked on it over the weekend, I came to the same conclusion as you did.  While your second comment would also normally be correct, I left out a requirement that I didn't think was pertinent but I suppose it was.  The property I am applying the RequireIf attribute to, is only required for one particular client.  I'm taking a shortcut here since the particular RetrievalMethodID value of 10 only exists for the client making the request.  Thanks for the response.